# Network icons are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Any idea why the Hot Network Questions suddenly look like this on P.SE?  (But not here on Meta.P.SE, for whatever reason...)

> [image]

Comment: icons look okay to me (Chrome 46 and FF 42 on Windoze 7)

Comment: Oh, I should have posted that.  This screenshot was taken in Firefox 42, on Windows 8.1.  I'm seeing similar errors on other StackExchange sites, but again not on their respective Metas

Comment: I have Firefox 42.0 on Windows 10, both fully updated. No problems for me.

Comment: I'm seeing it too on Firefox F2 and Win7

Comment: Same on Chrome on OS:X

Comment: reported (and said to be fixed) at MSE: [Site icons misaligned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270009/165773)

Comment: Bad designer was chastised. All is well now.